# estoy utilizando este metodo recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer() y e genera este error AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'

Tags: opencv

hola estoy utilizando este metodo
recognizer =cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer()
pero me esta generando este error                                                   #
^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'

tengo el siguiente codigo

```css
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

ruta_datos = '/home/robot/ProyectoRobot pc/interfaz final pantalla 7_/Proyect  2/Reconocimiento Facial/Data' #Coloco la ruta donde estan las imagenes caoturada s
Listas_per = os.listdir(ruta_datos) # enlisto las capertas
print('Lista de personas: ', Listas_per)

#creoa array para entreamiento  con el fin de tener etiqueta para la identidicacion por persona
labels = []
rostros_datos = []
label = 0 # creo contador para almacernar en labels

#empiezo a leer las imagenes 

for nombre_direccion  in Listas_per:                                                                                    # coloco la ruta de donde se leeran las imagenes 
    ruta = ruta_datos + '/' + nombre_direccion 
    print('Leyendo las imágenes')

    # empiezo a leer cada una de las imagenes 

    for archivoN in os.listdir(ruta):
        print('Rostros: ', nombre_direccion  + '/' + archivoN)

        labels.append(label)                                                                                        #ingreso el valor del label
        rostros_datos.append(cv2.imread(ruta+'/'+archivoN,0))                                                       #ingreso  cada una de las imagenes en escalas de griese 
        image = cv2.imread(ruta+'/'+archivoN,0)                                                             # se leen las imagenes y se transforman a escala de grises 
        cv2.imshow('image',image)
        cv2.waitKey(10)
    
    label = label + 1                                                                                               #incremento el contador label para que asigne el  0 a la primera carpeta que lea y siga sumando 1  ala carpeta siguiente 

recognizer =cv2.face.EigenFaceRecognizer_create()                                                   # Método para entrenar el reconocedor

print("Entrenando...")                                                                                               # escriboo para saber si esta haciendo el prcoceso
recognizer.train(rostros_datos, np.array(labels))                                                                    # Entrenando el reconocedor de rostros np.array es numpy array

recognizer.write('modeloEigenFace.xml')                                                                     ## Almacenando el modelo obtenido
print("Modelo almacenado...")                                                                                       # notificar que se ha almacenado el modelo
```

en todo lo que he leido dice que debo instalar python -m pip install --user opencv-contrib-python
pero estoy usando manajaro y no me deje hacer dichas instalaciones. me da la siguiente respuest
his environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try 'pacman -S
python-xyz', where xyz is the package you are trying to
install.

```
If you wish to install a non-Arch-packaged Python package,
create a virtual environment using 'python -m venv path/to/venv'.
Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip.

If you wish to install a non-Arch packaged Python application,
it may be easiest to use 'pipx install xyz', which will manage a
virtual environment for you. Make sure you have python-pipx
installed via pacman.
```

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

como podria solucionar

Comment: Si, es así, instalar paquetes de python  a nivel del sistema operativo solo lo puedes hacer con las herramientas del SO y privilegios administrativos. De todas formas esto es una mala práctica, en python se trabaja con entorno virtuales, es decir una copia local de python en la carpeta de tu proyecto, aquí si podrías actualizar cualquier paquete mediante `pip`, te sugiero que leas esto: https://docs.python.org/es/3.10/library/venv.html

Comment: gracias, ya logre resolver con la tienda de manjaro

Comment: igual leere tu recomendacion para estar mas clara